# Why I get AWS repository ARN could not be added to restrict access?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

I create new policy which restrict access to repository.

I copy repository ARN:

[image]

But get error:

[image]

**Why so I get this error and how to fix it?**

**UPD**
I have added similar policies before:

[image]

Can not understand what is wrong now (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heh... answer my own question: I must type `Region`, `Account`, `Repository name` manually. They are not detected automatically from `ARN`

[image]